# Best Method to Manipulate a CfnParameter String in aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

I'm trying in vain to do this. Here is the scenario:

We are creating a CloudFormation Stack that will generate a CodePipeline, that will pull another stack definition from git and deploy it, using the **CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction**

The repo and branch etc. are provided as **CfnParamaters** and the subsequent stack name we would like to base off a concatenation of the repo name and branch name.
However in some cases the repo might be named with an underscore or other special character that is invalid for a **stackName**.

I've attempted to manipulate the parameter strings using Macro's but I didnt get anywhere near something useful and running a .replace() function on the **repoStr.valueAsString** property modifies the CDK's "Token" pointer, not the resulting paramter which is declared at runtime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I can see:

First is to read the actual parameter value at synthesis time, then you can use the `.replace` function on parameter value. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ssm.StringParameter.html#static-value-wbr-from-wbr-lookupscope-parametername

Second is to use CloudFormation intristic function to split the parameter and join the fragments back in allowed manner. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html